# Pause HTML mp4 video when clicking outside of modal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5-video

I've been trying to get the video to stop playing when I close the modal by clicking outside of the modal. I've been able to do it when the user clicks the "x" inside of the modal box. It's using html video, and the video is in mp4 format.

HTML

```
<div class="fusion-modal modal fade modal-1 video in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-1" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content fusion-modal-content" style="background-color:#ffffff">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" aria-label="Close">×</button>
            <h3 class="modal-title fusion-responsive-typography-calculated" id="modal-heading-1" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" data-fontsize="24" style="--fontSize:24; line-height: 1.45;" data-lineheight="34.8px"></h3>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body fusion-clearfix">
            <div id="player-overlay">
               <div class="vsc-controller"></div>
               <video id="videoId" poster="/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/video-thumbnail.png" controls="controls" width="100%" height="150">
                  <source src="[video].mp4" type="video/mp4">
               </video>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var vid = document.getElementById("#videoId");
  $('button.close').click(function(){
     vid.pause();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check target elements  is your modal or not via `element.target`. If not pause your video.

Example:

```
$(function() {
$(document).on('click', function(element) {
        if (!$(element.target).closest('.fusion-modal').length) {
           $("#videoId").pause();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Issue with Avada I have to start every script with ```jQuery(document).ready(function($) { ```, so this code is throwing up an error. I wrote it like ```jQuery(document).on('click', function(element)``` but got a "$ is not a function" error on the next line @Shree

Comment: `$ is not a function` indicate that  jQuery library is not loaded properly. See console -> network tab . Also see updated answer . Short form of `document.ready` .

Comment: I replaced ```.fusion-modal``` with ```.modal-dialog``` and it worked. Thanks!